# How to call "SetDlgItemText" in custom class?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I have created Dialog based MFC application(c++). `OnBnClickedButton` prints data on edit control using `SetDlgItemText()`. Now I want to use `SetDlgItemText` in custom class(newly created class) but getting error "Debug assertion failed".

```
class test: public CDialogEx
{
public:
    void upd(CString);
};

void test::upd(CString a)
{
    SetDlgItemText(IDC_EDIT6,a);
}

void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton4()
{
    test obj;
    obj.upd("Hello");
}
```

[image: Error screenshot]

Comment: Have you pressed "Retry" as the dialog told you? This takes you straight to the code of the `ASSERT` in the MFC source, often giving enough clues to solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You can only set a dialog item, when the dialog window itself is created.

The Dialog gets created when `Create` or `DoModal` is called. As long as you have just an instance of a dialog class, you can not access any of the windows inside of it, when the dialog isn't created.

Usually you should use the DDX routines to exchange data between the dialog class and the windows.

PS: This seems to me as a beginner MFC question. Please read some tutorials.

Comment: MFCApplication3  has dlgAbout.DoModal() ,which is getting called!

Comment: But you create a new object in your click handler. How can you assume that this new object is related to the current object? In other words: You never call DoModal or Create for the test class. If you search for a tutorial, just use google...

Comment: @Bahubali https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/589/A-Beginners-Guide-to-Dialog-Based-Applications-Par

Comment: @AndrewTruckle not sure if the codeproject article will be helpful as it is about Visual Studio 6 and, as you know, in VS20xx the wizards are very different (_if_ they work at all).

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in your event handler

```
void CMFCApplication3Dlg::OnBnClickedButton4()
{
    CString str; //Initialize this string to whatever you wish to
    GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT6)->SetWindowText(str);
}
```

Hope this helps.

p.s I know this ans has nothing to do with SetDlgItemText, it's just another way of setting text in mfc.